# How to match id in javascript for dynamically added field on html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

In our rails app, dynamic fields can be added to the form. Here is a html source code for the dynamically added field `order_order_items_attributes_1413563163040_unit_price`:

```
<div class="input decimal required order_order_items_unit_price">
<label class="decimal required control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163040_unit_price">
<abbr title="required">*</abbr>
Unit Price($)
</label>
<input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163040_unit_price" class="numeric decimal required span5 span5" type="number" step="any" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413563163040][unit_price]">
</div>
```

As you can see, there is 13 digits string in field's id and it is randomly generated when the field is added. How we can match (locate) this type of random id in javascript? rails app uses jquery (ex, `$('#order_order_items_attributes_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_unit_price').change(function (){})`).

We are new to this css type of id match. More detail would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the id value?  If not, are you just looking for any id that matches this pattern (though presumably, there can be more than one of them)?  Or, is there some means for identifying the particular id that matches this scheme that you want?  You aren't giving us enough information on what you're trying to do9.  The answers so far are wild guesses at what you really want to do or are just giving you tools that could be used.

Comment: 13 digits in the ID string is not known before being generated. Those 13 digits will repeat in other fields' id when generating at the same time.

Comment: You didn't answer my other questions.  Are you just looking for ANY id in the entire document that has that pattern of characters in the ID?  And, what do you do if there is more than one that matches that pattern?

Comment: We are looking for id for paired unit price and qty. Whenever there is change on any unit price or qty, a javascript function will kick in to recaculate the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first decide what algorithm you're using for matching the id values.  Based on your comments (it is not specified precistly in your question), it appears you want to find all ids that start with `"order_order_items_attributes_"` and end with `"_unit_price"` and have a sequence of digits between them.

You can do that like this by find all the ids that start with the thing you want and then filtering them to things that only match all three criteria:

```
// find ids that match this pattern: order_order_items_attributes_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_unit_price
var orderItemRegex = /^order_supplier_id_\d+_unit_price$/;
$("[id^='order_supplier_id_']").filter(function(index) {
    return orderItemRegex.test(this.id);
}).change(function() {
    // this will be only the ids that match
});
```

This uses jQuery to make a list of all objects that have an id that starts with `"order_supplier_id_"`.  It then filters through that list eliminating any objects who don't match the full regex `/^order_supplier_id_\d+_unit_price$/` that defines your pattern and then hooks up the `.change()` event handler to only the objects that pass the regex test.

Comment: It looks going to work. How we can iterate through each of ids in the list generated?

Comment: @user938363 - I don't understand what you mean by `iterate through each of ids in the list generated`.  There's a list of DOM objects in the jQuery object above which can be iterated with `.each()`.  If you want to extract the numeric part of the ID, you can add a group to the regex and match the regex on the id to get just the numeric id.

Comment: We need to calculate subtotal by doing unit_price * qty for each pair and adding all subtotals together. Doing subtotal like: $('#order_order_items_xxxxxxxx_unit_price').val() * $('#order_order_items_xxxxxxxx_qty').val(). If we can generate 2 lists of the ids, one for unit_price and another for qty, then we can perform this multiplication by retrieving the val of them.

Comment: @user938363 - You're making another part to this question.  Now that this question has been answered and you have a list of the objects you originally asked about, I'd suggest you ask another question on how to take this list of objects and do some calculations using it.  In that new question, please be very clear about where in your HTML the price and quantity come from because that isn't obvious from your current question.

Comment: Just added a new question. Not sure if the question is clear enough. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
$("input").prop("id");
```

That'll search for your input field and find the id property.

Comment: You didn't understand the question

Comment: He's trying to find the randomly generated id from the input field.  Right?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `for` attribute of your `<label>`:

```
var selector = $('.decimal.required.control-label').eq(0).attr('for'),
    element = $('#'+selector);

console.log(element);
// [<input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163040_unit_price" ... >]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute selector to match an id that "contains" the specified value, using `[attr*=value]`. Like:

```
$("[id*='order_supplier_id']").change(function() {

});
```

[**MDN's docs on attribute selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) specifies the kinds of selectors you can use to match the attribute, among them:

> **[attr*=value]**
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as substring.

Comment: The id of all element inserted dynamically starts with 'order_order_items_'. if we do $("[id*='order_order_items_']"), then it would match every dynamic element.

Comment: Then look for how it ends, instead of how it starts.

Comment: Is $("[*id='_unit_price']") going to match any id ending with '_unit_price' ? Is there a way we can match id which starts and ends with 'order_order_items_' and '_unit_prie'?

Comment: @user938363 - `[attr^=value]` means *starts with*, `[attr$=value]` means *ends with* - So, in this case would be `$("[id^='order_order_items'][id$='_unit_prie']")`

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain an array of element IDs that gets updated each time the form element is added. Then call your change method on the elements in your array. But that isn't necessary if the change event callback is identical for all the new elements. Just call it on the class.