# How to perform multiplication in JavaScript for dynamically added field on HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is HTML source code for one pair of dynamically added elements `unit_price` and `qty`.

```
<label class="decimal required control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163040_unit_price">
<input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163040_unit_price" class="numeric decimal required span5 span5" type="number" step="any" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413563163040][unit_price]">
</div>
<div class="input integer required order_order_items_qty">
<label class="integer required control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163040_qty">
<input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163040_qty" class="numeric integer required span5 span5" type="number" step="1" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413563163040][qty]">
</div>
```

Whenever there is change in any unit_price, then we can do:

```
// find ids that match this pattern: order_order_items_attributes_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_unit_price
var orderItemRegex = /^order_order_items_\d+_unit_price$/;
$("[id^='order_order_items_']").filter(function(index) {
    return orderItemRegex.test(this.id);
}).change(function() {
    //here is what needs to be done. There may be more than one pair of unit price and qty on the form.
    For each pair of unit price & qty do {
    total += unit_price * qty
    }
    //update total
    $('order_total').val(total);
});
```

The same process could be repeated again for qty whenever there is qty change in any qty field.

We are looking for solution which iterates through the list and retrieves each of the id of unit price and qty.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for a solution; we need you to show us what you've tried and why you think it didn't work. This helps us to avoid things you've already tried and show us that you're not just asking for your work to be done for you.

Comment: The question is the followup from another question posted. It may be odd if you read this question only.

Comment: If it's going to be out of context without knowing about the other question, you may want to link to the other question.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429673/how-to-match-id-in-javascript-for-dynamically-added-field-on-html

Comment: Despite the context of having another question about the same part of your code, it still looks like you're asking us to write it for you, that's not how SO works.

Comment: Forgive me @TankorSmash and $jprofitt for providing a working example. If the OP's reputation was 1, I would have considered this a typical "do my work for me", and blown it off. But I think that given the complexity of the HTML attributes (UGLY!!!), they were probably genuinely stumped as to how to even begin. @user938363 If the HTML is within your control, I **strongly** encourage you to think of ways you could simplify it! In particular, use CSS classes to distinguish price and quantity fields, and put the numeric value in a `data-*` attribute, so you don't have to parse those crazy ids.

Comment: Troy Gizzi, We can not control the user behavior. If a user decides to add quite a few items to the order, then the form can get quite complex. The worse is that we don't know the ids of those user added elements and have to find a way to retrieve and match them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestions:**

1. Build an array containing the numeric portions of the ids from the price/qty fields. Your regex approach was close, but needed to be tweaked slightly to extract just that portion of the id.
2. Build a function to loop through those numbers, use them to fetch the price/qty pairs from the form, and then calculate the subtotal.
3. Call that function as soon as the page loads (only necessary if the form is prepopulated).
4. Call that function whenever a price or quantity changes.

**Working Example:**

Note: I added values to the form fields for convenience. Change them to see the subtotal update. And you'll have to add more code or field validation rules to account for negative numbers, etc.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  // find ids that match this pattern: order_order_items_attributes_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_unit_price
  var orderItemRegex = /^order_order_items_attributes_(\d+)_unit_price$/;
  var $editableFields = $("input[id$='_unit_price'], input[id$='_qty']");
  var fieldNumbers = (function() {
   var results = [];
   $("[id$='_unit_price']").each(function () {
    var numericId = orderItemRegex.exec(this.id)[1];
    results.push(numericId);
   });
   console.log(results);
   return results;
  })();
  function updateSubtotal() {
   var subtotal = 0;
   $.each(fieldNumbers, function (index, fieldNumber) {
    var priceString = $('#order_order_items_attributes_' + fieldNumber + '_unit_price').val();
    var priceAmount = priceString ? parseFloat(priceString.replace(/\$\,/g, '')) : 0;
    var quantityString = $('#order_order_items_attributes_' + fieldNumber + '_qty').val();
    var quantityAmount = quantityString ? parseFloat(quantityString.replace(/\,/g, '')) : 0;
    subtotal += (priceAmount * quantityAmount);
   });
   $('#subtotal').text('$' + subtotal.toFixed(2));
  }
  updateSubtotal();
  $editableFields.change(updateSubtotal);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <label class="decimal required control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163040_unit_price">Price</label>
 <input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163040_unit_price" class="numeric decimal required span5 span5" type="number" step="any" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413563163040][unit_price]" value="5.95"/>
</div>
<div class="input integer required order_order_items_qty">
 <label class="integer required control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163040_qty">Quantity</label>
 <input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163040_qty" class="numeric integer required span5 span5" type="number" step="1" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413563163040][qty]" value="1"/>
</div>
<label class="decimal required control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163052_unit_price">Price</label>
<input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163052_unit_price" class="numeric decimal required span5 span5" type="number" step="any" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413563163052][unit_price]" value="0.78"/>
</div>
<div class="input integer required order_order_items_qty">
 <label class="integer required control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163052_qty">Quantity</label>
 <input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413563163052_qty" class="numeric integer required span5 span5" type="number" step="1" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413563163052][qty]" value="3"/>
</div>
<div>
 <label>Subtotal:</label>
 <span id="subtotal"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Troy Gizzi, thank you very much. The answer is more than what we expected.

Comment: No problem. One follow-up thought: If line items are dynamically added/removed at runtime (this looked like more of a "product catalog" than a "cart", so I wasn't sure), then you'll probably want to extract the IIFE after `var fieldNumbers = ` into a separate reusable named function, and call it whenever items are added/removed, in order to update the `fieldNumbers` array accordingly.

Comment: Troy Gizzi, it is an order form! A user can add or remove a product from the form. Your answer will make our dynamic forms more user friendly. Thanks again!

Comment: In that case, you might want to use a non-editable `label` instead of an `input` for the prices. And never trust a price or subtotal sent in from the client; that should be calculated server-side, using trusted prices from your database. Otherwise any user with a basic grasp of JavaScript could place an order using whatever prices they wanted. (All this is assuming that users are _not_ allowed to set their own price, of course...)

Comment: You are right. The unit price should be label and qty is an input field (user can only change the qty). Also a $('#.._qty').change(function(){}) will be used to respond to a qty change.